# Arch Missing local route

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I have an arch Linux box that is exhibiting some very strange behavior.  On boot, I have a script that gets called to bring the interfaces up & configure them as I need.  i.e.:

```
ip link add link eth0 name mgt10 type vlan id 10
ip link add link eth0 name guest20 type vlan id 20

ip link set mgt10 up
ip addr add 10.10.0.1/24 dev mgt10

ip link set guest20 up
ip addr add 10.20.0.1/24 dev guest20
```

With this script being called, I see the interfaces are up, and have the appropriate IP assigned:

```
# ip addr show
1: mgt10@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.1/24 scope global mgt10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: guest20@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.0.1/24 scope global guest10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But the problem is, for whatever reason, it didn't create a local route for mgt10.

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.20.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 guest20
```

I get no errors that I can see, and if I then manually delete the IP from the interface, and re-add (copy/pasting the same command), the route comes up as expected, and I have no problems.

I have no clue why this is.  Could it be that the physical link was in-the-process of coming up, and the system hiccuped?  Is there some way to ensure that the interfaces are in a ready-state for assignment?  am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you're using the ip link commands in a boot up script? There are several examples on the arch wiki about how to create a vlan using systemctl. It may be worth modifying the examples here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLAN#Starting_at_boot

This gives you the benefit of enabling the vlans as a service and having logging happen if something goes wrong.

In addition to systemctl, you could also try using netctl. There are example scripts in /etc/netctl/examples for vlans that you could modify. Again, this would allow you to enable the profiles so they run on boot, check logfiles on how they're running with journalctl, etc.

Comment: While I appreciate your response, this really isn't an answer to the question.  I have considered using systemctl and netctl... and unfortunately, I cannot for a long list of complicated reasons.  I'm mostly curious as to why the basic underlying commands fail to do the job they were designed to do.

Comment: In that case, does journalctl show anything failing while the script is running at boot up?

Comment: No errors... (as I said previously)  I've even gone as far as to dump all output (stderr and stdout) of every command to a file during boot.  It just doesn't add the routes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently on a Debian 11 box - no local route being created for the interface, but no errors.

Your problem was different cause, I think. In my case the problem was I had manually edited the /etc/network/interfaces file, and neglected to add the subnet mask to the address line. So the file had

```
iface vmbr0 inet static
  address 10.100.17.56
```

instead of

```
iface vmbr0 inet static
  address 10.100.17.56/24
```

And so the OS rightly did not create a local network route, since it interpreted that line as having an implicit "/32" at the end.

There was a clue in the `ip a` output, but I missed it at first... the mask on the IP was /32, not /24:

```
6: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:62:0b:d5:a2:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.100.17.56/32 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```